# use value of array in another array to parse sentences

Tags: javascript, chatbot, string-parsing, sentence

I am creating a chatbot and i need help, i have googled alot but nothing helped me.

I want to do something like this:

```
var input = $('#InputField').html(); //consider it as hi, how are you!

var commonGreetings = ["hi", "hello"];
var questions  = [{commonGreetings} +",how are you!"]; // i want to check if first word of sentence is in the array named commonGreetings.
```

//then

```
var answers  = ["i am fine, thank you!"];

    if(questions.indexOf(input ) > -1){
        $('#output').html(answers[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Regex the input using case insensitive match
2. Use Array.includes(matched.toLowerCase()

```js
const input = "  Hello World!"

const commonGreetings = ["hi", "hello"]
const rx = /^\s*(\w+)/
const m = rx.exec(input, 'i')
if (m) {
  const found = m[1].toLowerCase()
  if (commonGreetings.includes(found)) {
    console.log(`Found a match for ${found}`)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First solution:

   ```
   var firstWord = input.match(/\w*/)[0];
   if(commonGreetings.indexOf(firstWord) > -1){
       $('#output').html(answers[0]);
   }
   ```
2. Alternatively, you can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to generate array of questions like this:

   ```
   var questions = commonGreetings.map(function(commonGreeting) {
       return commonGreeting + ', how are you!'
   });
   ```